# Why I cant use join with regex in mysql?

Tags: mysql, regex

I want to find some invalid postal codes in my database(which has more than 5 million records) using a regex which i tested in www.regex101.com and some other regex test websites and it works fine. I also need to join the table with another one to find more details about that record. But the query doesnt work and keeps searching without ANY errors. I have used this exact regex for another query without the join and for only one table and it works. So i think its not about back references which some other developers told me.

This is the query ive tried and didnt work:

```
"SELECT a.Name,a.AdslTel,a.Mobile, b.CodePosty 
 FROM on_customers as a, on_customers_detail as b 
 WHERE a.Serial=b.CustomerRef and a.TownshipRef='1' 
 AND b.CodePosty NOT REGEXP '^[13456789]{5}[1-9]([[:digit:]]){3}([1- 
 9]){1}$' or b.CodePosty REGEXP '([[:digit:]])\1{5,}' "
```

And this is the query that worked just fine :

```
"SELECT * FROM on_customers WHERE Mobile NOT REGEXP '^(09) 
([[:digit:]]){9}$' 
 or Mobile REGEXP '([[:digit:]])\1{5,}' "
```

Comment: Your two queries are very different, not only in the regex logic.  So, I _don't_ think backtracking has anything to do with your problem, and if it did, the query probably won't not even execute anyway.  Maybe add some sample data to your question if you want to get better help here.

Comment: Hard to tell without sample data and expected results but you likely want to put the `OR`ed expression in parenthesis to force precedence as otherwise the `AND`s have precedence -- `... (b.CodePosty NOT REGEXP '^[13456789]{5}[1-9]([[:digit:]]){3}([1- 
 9]){1}$' or b.CodePosty REGEXP '([[:digit:]])\1{5,}')`. And you should modern join syntax like `... FROM ... INNER JOIN ... ON ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NOT a OR b` means `(NOT a) OR b` -- perhaps you want `NOT (a OR b)`?

`a AND b OR c` means `(a AND b) OR c` -- perhaps you want `a AND (b OR c)`?

Add parentheses, at least when you are unsure of the precedence rules.